Is this universal dependency relationship a 'property'?
P1. Each thing, in order to exist, depends existentially on something else (universal dependence).
P2. The relation of dependence (between things) does not depend on any particular thing but is a general property among all things.
C. Therefore, the relation of dependence is, in itself, independent of the things that compose it.
Formally:

Let x1, x2, x3, …, xn represent a series of things, where each xi depends on another thing xj, with i ≠ j.


The relation of dependence D(xi, xj) exists among all x, but it is not conditioned by any specific thing, as it is a property of the structure of interrelations.


Therefore, the dependence D is independent of the specific objects it relates.

So, what is independent is not the things themselves, but the structure of dependence among them. The dependence remains constant and does not depend on the identity of the particular objects.
Question: (i) does my question make sense? (ii) Can I call D 'property' and would it be well formalized?
Thanks in advance.

"Depends existentially" is just a very vague term, as is "thing" since you haven't said what kinds of things you're talking about. Try to make it concrete and specific. What does the number -3.4 depend existentially on? What did the Big Bang depend existentially on?

Indeed, to the extent that people are always inquiring the meta properties of such a universal metaphysical dependence property as reflected in a recent another post…

This sounds like Spinoza's formulation of the principle of sufficient reason (PSR):"Nothing exists of which it cannot be asked, what is the cause (or reason), why it exists... The reason why a circle or triangle exists, or why it does not exist, does not follow from the nature of these things, but from the order of the whole of corporeal Nature." Although it is formally predicable of things, many would not take what PSR asserts as their "property" for the same reason that they do not take existence itself as such a property.

P1. Maybe... P2. Does it hold for every relation?

@MauroALLEGRANZA Yes, in principle, it's something I want to consider for anything (object, property, event, process....).

@Conifold I understand, but then, what exactly would the PSR be asserting? A characteristic, a quality...?"

An "order of the whole of corporeal Nature", a law of metaphysics, a property of the world or a second order property of existence, perhaps, but not a property of the "nature of these things". "One does not add a thing to the concept of a thing by further declaring that the thing exists... Otherwise it would not be exactly the same thing that exists, but something more than we had thought in the concept" (Kant). Declaring that existence depends on something else does not add it either. Isn't that how your "relation of dependence is, in itself, independent of the things that compose it"?

Broadly no, and to be taken seriously can you re-phrase the Question?
Can you say what might be lost through dropping either 'dependency' or 'relationship'? Failing that, will you state that you don't care?

@RobbieGoodwin By "dependency relationship", I simply mean that x depends on y; if y disappears, x disappears. Now, y is also not an ultimate foundation, as it also depends on another element, z, and so on all the way down. If we imagine a universe where all its elements possess this dependency relationship, to which category would this relationship belong?

@Ian Thanks and why not simply be clear? Is it a 'dependency' or a   'relationship' or what?
if it's a 'dependency relationship' how is that different from either a 'dependency' or a 'relationship'?

@RobbieGoodwin I guess because every dependency is a relationship but not every relationship is a dependency.  Relationship is a type of bond or connection, and specifically dependency is a founding bond.

@Ian Yes but how could 'universal dependency relationship' ever be helpful?
I still believe there can be no 'universal (anything)…', which makes any idea of 'universal dependency relationship' nonsense.
Would you like to correct that by dropping 'universal'?
Back at the OQ, it remains my sole and simple aim to point out that while we might perm any two of three, 'universal dependency relationship' is too much for any 'property'?

@RobbieGoodwin  By universal, I mean 'invariable' here, as when we refer to a constant when certain conditions are met. Every time those conditions are met, that constant recurs. In this case, it is a constant always given by an infinite regression of dependency levels. I want to know (i) if this invariable can be called 'independent' (as it would not depend on a more fundamental element) and (ii) how it should be classified: property, characteristic...

You seem to be using special definitions of your own. For instance, both constants and invariables are normally seen without reference to any conditions. How do you justify that?

@RobbieGoodwin You seem to operate with an unjustified nominalism. Precisely the fact that invariables and constants are independent justifies my point: there is a feature in the dependency sequence that is independent.

If you really believe that, go ahead! To me, that's so much sophistry. If you'd like, why not Ask SE Philosophy Members to vote? In fact, why wait? Please, SE Philosophy Members, tell us how you vote?

@RobbieGoodwin You yourself have said that you do not ‘believe’ that there can be anything universal and you have not justified it: that is sophistry. Read it. I don't know how the votes work and I'm not interested in it, but you can make them vote if you want.

@RobbieGoodwin Clearly you have not acted with any hermeneutic benevolence towards my question from the beginning. I am asking how my point could be clarified and how it could be better formulated, and all you have done is launch sceptical attacks. The purpose of a forum is to help not to destroy.

I suggest the main point of Comments is to seek clarification. Who doubts that? Who embraces 'hermeneutic benevolence' please, speak up!
Despite your disbelief or misunderstanding, I tried to show you the simple principle, most obviously expounded by Sherlock Holmes nearly 150 years ago, that the first approach should be to remove all negatives. Sherlock specifically said '…eliminate the impossible…' and I invite you to show a useful difference.
If you see a 'universal dependency relationship… as a 'property', can you re-phrase it, or does the whole idea depend on the original wording?

@RobbieGoodwin I don't see how either term can be made more parsimonious. A synonym would be something like ‘invariant foundational relationship’.

Then why try to drag parsimony into this? If you can't paraphrase the OQ why not take SE's suggestion and go to Chat?

@RobbieGoodwin Im going to stop replying to you because I honestly don't see that you are helping me at all. You haven't suggested any way to improve my question.

Good for you and I never hoped to do the improvement for you; merely to point out that improvement was lacking.
Prolly your last chance before SE enforces a move to Chat: why not ignore every word I've Posted, yet re-phrase the Question to account for some of what others said?

Sorry, Ian: I just noticed where you claimed I said I did not believe there could be anything universal. No, Ian… that's no part of anything I did or ever might say; purely your own misinterpretation of something I didn't say. You're welcome either to retract your misinterpretation, or to meet SE's standards of clarity and honesty. The choice is yours and which would you prefer?

P2. As before, would you rather re-phrase this part or can you explain how it could ever help to suggest that
'The relation of dependence (between things) does not depend on any particular thing but is a general property among all things?'
'The relation of dependence (between things) does not depend on any particular thing but is a general property among all things.
'The relation of dependence (between things) does not depend on any particular thing but is a general property among all things.
'The relation of dependence (between things) does not depend on any particular thing but is a general property among all things.

I am simply talking about a general property that occurs in all those relationships: 'B grounds A means that if B ceases to exist, A ceases to exist; B, at the same time, depends on C, ad infinitum.' It is a sort of antifoundationalism, and I am merely referring to a general characteristic present in all dependecy relationships. Everyone has understood this except you, and you are the only one who has not made constructive or helpful comments on this post.

Instead of being so destructive, why don’t you suggest a better way to phrase P2 in English?

Instead of being so defensive, why don't you consider the value of paring down and pruning out?
As soon as P1 said 'Each thing, in order to exist, depends existentially on…' any and everything following was clearly based on existence depending existentially… at best confusing; more likely, made meaningless by tautology… here, attempting to define existence in terms of existence.
Will you clear up that doubt, at least?

If you can bring yourself to consider the value of paring, pruning or clarifying why not look at P2 in light of whether it’s reasonable to ask what the relation of dependence… might depend on?

Why not explain how as they stand, or even reworded any way you like, P1 and P2 do - or could - demand the conclusion, C?
That ‘the relation of dependence is, in itself, independent of the things that compose it’ might be wholly valid but still, it would not be helpful here.
What matters here is how C is derived from P1 and P2, which I suggest could never be possible.

You might say that 'dependence on A' was a property of B but how could that justify the Question title 'Is this universal dependency relationship a 'property'?' How could it justify anything in the exposition or subsequent discussion thus far?
